# How to get text from textBlock during SelectionChangeEvent from a ListBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox

I am try to get a text from my TextBlock during item select from my Listbox.

Here is my code for listbox in my xaml file..

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" Height="535" Margin="7,0,12,0" 
      SelectionChanged="selectedItem" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding}">

    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <toolkit:WrapPanel FlowDirection="LeftToRight" 
                ItemWidth="215" ItemHeight="215" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate x:Uid="info">
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Border>
                    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,6,0,0" 
                        Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                        Source="{Binding imageSource}" />
                </Border>
                <TextBlock x:Name="path" Foreground="Transparent" 
                    Text="{Binding imagePath}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

</ListBox>
```

For my c# code i am using a selectionChangedEvent method that will handle tap event but i can not figure out how to get content of my TextBlock element.

```
private void selectedItem(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //I need to take the content of my textblock w/c carry the path for
    //my image to be use to share using ShareMediaTask.    
    //path = the content of my textblock

    var task = new ShareMediaTask();
    task.FilePath = path;
    task.Show();
}
```

I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if imagePath is a Property of a class, try this

```
var item = listBox.SelectedItem as className; // like ShareMediaTask

var task = new ShareMediaTask();
task.FilePath = item.imagePath;
task.Show();
```

Comment: Yes sir imagePath is a property of a class. Thank you very much sir! now its working!

Answer (score 0):

If it's sent from the textblock, it would be your sender ... so you can do something like

```
var text = ((TextBlock)sender).Text;
```

Otherwise, you'll have to reference the property that it's binding to ...
Why, oh why will you name your textblock `path` ?? it'll confuse the hell out of everybody ... call it `TextBlockPath`, this way it's not ambiguous with just a path ...