# Windows phone 8: get value item of listbox

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a listbox. Every item has an image and title (binding from my list). When I click an item of the listbox, how do I get the title value of that item.

Comment: That's a very specific question that would require you to post the XAML used to template your listbox.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

create an event in ListBox called "SelectionChanged" and map it the method in the code behind of the XAML file. In the .cs file get the value from myListBox.SelectedItem and cast it to your list item type.

EX: in XAML file

```
<ListBox x:Name="myListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"     
  SelectionChanged="myListBox_SelectionChanged">
```

in xaml.cs file:

```
private void myListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var mySelectedItem = myListBox.SelectedItem as myObject;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

There are already few similar questions ([first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19968648/how-to-get-text-from-textblock-during-selectionchangeevent-from-a-listbox), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21480453/get-data-from-clicked-item-in-listbox)). I'll try to show you an example (little extending this what @KirtiSagar ([if it helps accept his solution as it's the same method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21834898/2681948)) has said):

Let's assume that your ItemClass look like this:

```
public class ItemClass
{
    public Uri ImagePath { get; set; }
    public string Tile { get; set; }  // I used string as an example - it can be any class
}
```

And you Bind it to your ListBox like this:

```
<ListBox Name="myList" Grid.Row="2">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
              <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}"/>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Tile}"/>
          </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

It is a very simple example but should show you an overview how it works.

Then in my Page and Constructor I need to add my Collection and subscribe to events:

```
ObservableCollection<ItemClass> items = new ObservableCollection<ItemClass>();

public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    myList.ItemsSource = items;
    myList.SelectionChanged += myList_SelectionChanged;
}
```

The `SelectinChanged` event can be used for your purpose in many ways. For example you can use its [SelectionChangedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.selectionchangedeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) properties. I will show some methods which will produce the same result. I mixed some things on purpose just to show how it can be done.

```
private void myList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   if (myList.SelectedItem != null)
   {
       string myTile = ((sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as ItemClass).Tile;
       // you can also get your item like this - using EventArgs properties:
       string myTileToo = ((ItemClass)(e.AddedItems[0])).Tile;
   }
   // also you can get this by SelectedIndex and your Item Collection
   if ((sender as ListBox).SelectedIndex >= 0)
   {
       string myTileThree = items[myList.SelectedIndex].Tile;
   }
}
```

Note that your `LisBox` can work in different [SelectionModes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.selectionmode(v=vs.110).aspx) for example `Multipe` - you can also try to use that if you need it (there are properties `SelectedItems` and `AddedItems` / `RemovedItems`, which are `IList`).

Comment: @Romasz is it possible to fire Tap event for Image inside ListBoxItem? I have an image and 2 text block in DataTemplate and I have added SelectionChanged event, but I want to add Tap event for Image to acquire different functionality. Can you suggest is it possible to do this?

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar It's hard for me to say, hence you provided too little information. I think you should be able to track the item that has been tapped somehow, I think I remember dealing with something like this, but for now I don't have much time and don't know the exact answer. Please add a separate question about this on SO, probably somebody will know.